# Is it possible to use WebPack CompressionPlugin standalone because create-react-app doesn't support custom config?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

So I have a `CompressionPlugin` configuration like this.

```js
{
    plugins: [
        new CompressionPlugin({
            filename: '[path].gz[query]',
            algorithm: 'gzip',
            test: /\.js$/,
            minRatio: 0.8,
        }),
    ];
}
```

However, I'm using `create-react-app` right now, which doesn't support custom config.

Although I can use `react-app-rewired` to fix this, I've noticed that when running this plugin, it just create individual `.gz` file for every javascript.

So is it really necessary to hook this plugin to WebPack?

Or if I can just `react-scripts build && npm run compress` for my `build` folder?

Is this also a valid option? Would it be any pitfalls I didn't know?